# Is there any function with complexity O(log n) whereas power(2, f) is not in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Cant figure this one out:

Is there a function `f` such that:

```
f(n) is in O(log n)
```

but,

```
2^(f(n)) is not in O(n)
```

Should be correct, but I don't understand why.

Comment: I meant ^ , in python its ** so I got used to it I guess lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, consider the following example:

A = logn + logn/2, so A = O(log n)

2<sup>A</sup> = 2<sup>logn + logn/2</sup> =  2<sup>logn</sup> * 2<sup>logn/2</sup> = n*n/2 = 1/2n<sup>2</sup> != O(n)

(More specifically, 2<sup>A</sup> = ω(n), meaning it grows strictly faster than a linear function.)

Comment: You have a very strange way of using the O-notation. Somhow you seem to use it as function that gives you the canonical representative of a class. But this might be hard to define and is not what the notation usually means. Instead it is a set of functions that are asymptotically bounded by some function. So you shoud write something like A ∈ O(log n) and 1/2n²∉O(n)

Comment: @dth Yep, Actually I've wrote the answer somehow it be more understandable for OP, and when I write O(1/2n^2) = n^2 This is not wrong in terms of functional perspective because the big O notation will be evaluated by the largest degree of the function. But in terms of implementation you are right 1/2n²∉O(n). Any way thanks to chepner that edited the answer, and makes it more realistic.

Answer (score -1):

Well, yes and no...

how precise are you on your definition ? What is `log(n)` for you ?

In Engineering `log(n)` usually means `log_10(n)`, in CS usually is `log_2(n)` however it is true that `O(log_m(n))` is in the same class of `O(log_h(n))`.

Then what you mean by `2**(fn(n))` ? `fn(n)` does return an integer ?

The problem is not well posed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the base is; `log_a(n)` and `log_b(n)` are within a constant factor of each other.

Comment: Then how is the question not well-posed?

Comment: @chepner, what is `f(n)` ? From the problem is a function that belongs to `O(logn)`, then, still from the question, `2^(f(n)) = O(n)` from mathematical definition the exponential need an integer exponent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation I need to suppose that f(n) return an integer, how this integer is related to n ?

Comment: @chepner, beside that we are not really talking about Big-O notation, but, more likely Big-Theta notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: Why do you think the exponent has to be an integer? The wikipedia article goes on to explain how exponentiation is defined for rational and real exponents.

Comment: @chepner finally I also explained in my answer that "O(log_m(n)) is in the same class of O(log_h(n))" where with "class" I meant class of complexity, but I hoped it was clear... Which is exactly your own comment at my answer.

Comment: @chepner, integer, real, or whatever thing you want, the point is that the result of `f(n)` must be related to its complexity... Beside that the exponential for thing different from integer is defined using integers, but is not the point...

Comment: Big-O notation can be used for things than algorithmic complexity. Your "answer" is merely a comment, and there is nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102271/discussion-between-siscia-and-chepner).